# Electron 'open-url' event isn't triggered while app isn't running on background

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, protocols, url-scheme

When I run my electron app on macOS, I want to read all parameters coming with deeplinkingUrl. I can able to get the deeplinkingUrl reading it from `process.argv` when my application invoked via protocol on Windows. But it is not possible on macOS because process.argv gives `-psn...` and it gives this parameter just one time when the app is launched for the first time.

I want to trigger `open-url` via invoking the protocol from browser while my app isn't running on background on macOS. But this event is triggered only while app is running. While app is not running, app will show up but it isn't navigate according to operation which comes with deeplinkingUrl.

I also wrote those in `package.json`:

```
"protocols": {
  "name": "My App",
  "schemes": [
    "myapp"
  ]
}
```

Those from the `electron.js`:

```
let clickToCallObj = {};
let deeplinkingUrl;
let mainWindow;

app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const isDefaultProtocolClientSet = app.isDefaultProtocolClient('myapp');

    deeplinkingUrl = url;

    clickToCallObj.operation = utils.getOperation(deeplinkingUrl); //e.g. myapp:/call/12345 -> operation: call

    if (mainWindow && isDefaultProtocolClientSet) {
        mainWindow.isMinimized() ? mainWindow.restore() : null;
        mainWindow.focus();

        sendClickToCallEvent(clickToCallObj, deeplinkingUrl); //takes the action with coming operation and deeplinkingUrl
    }
});
```

So, how can I get deeplinkingUrl when I invoke my app on macOS while it isn't running on background?

Answer (score 0):

1. `app.on('will-finish-launching', )` event should be caught just before the `app.on('ready', )`
2. `isInvokedWhileAppIsNotRunning` parameter is being set to true and being controlled after application loading has finished.
3. `Based on electron documentation, open-url event has used in will-finish-launching event regarding their occurrence order.`

   ```
   // Protocol handler for osx while application is not running in the background.
   app.on ('will-finish-launching' , () => {
       app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {


           event.preventDefault();

           deeplinkingUrl = url;

           const isDefaultProtocolClientSet    = app.isDefaultProtocolClient(getProtocolName());
           clickToCallObj.operation            = utils.getOperation(deeplinkingUrl);

           if (isDefaultProtocolClientSet) {
               clickToCallObj.isInvokedWhileAppIsNotRunning = true;
           }
       });
   });

   // Protocol handler for osx while the app is running in the background
   app.on('open-url', (event, url) => {
       event.preventDefault();

       const isDefaultProtocolClientSet = app.isDefaultProtocolClient(getProtocolName());

       clickToCallObj.operation = utils.getOperation(url);

       if (mainWindow && isDefaultProtocolClientSet) {
           mainWindow.isMinimized() ? mainWindow.restore() : null;
           mainWindow.focus();

           sendClickToCallEvent(clickToCallObj, url);
       }
   });
   ```